# Launch app when intent received

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch an app made with basic through an intent sent by Tasker.
After some searches, I found this code:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.rfo.MyNewApp.action.basic"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I add this code to my basic app manifest, compile it,
and then send an intent from Tasker, my basic app opens but it will give app stopped working error just when I send the intent

The intent im sending by tasker:

```
action:com.rfo.MyNewApp.action.basic
cat:none
mime type:none
target:activity
all other fields are empty
```

Comment: this question is more appropriate for a site like superuser.com or android.stackexchange.com which helps power users. StackOverflow is more for programming questions.

Comment: @ataulm: This questions seems appropriate for SO and not SU or stackexchange. OP is trying to launch his/her app, when receiving a specific `Intent` action.
@Alexander post the stacktrace of the error you receive when opening the app from the `Intent`.